# Set default Lockscreen background,when no Media Cover

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, lockscreen

I'm making a music player and i have a problem. I'm using remote controls for my player and they are visible on lockscreen. When song has cover i send it to Remote Contols and it shown on lockScreen, but i need to show default phone lockscreen background when song doesn't have cover - is it possible?
I tried this :

```
RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor editor = remoteControlClient.editMetadata(false);
editor.putBitmap(RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.BITMAP_KEY_ARTWORK, null).apply();
```

and this:

```
RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor editor = remoteControlClient.editMetadata(true);
```

and this:

`editor.clear();
editor.apply()`

But nothing helps, previos cover is still on lockscreen when i click next song.

Comment: Did you found a decision?

Comment: @konopko no, only decision for now is to set some default image

Comment: A now have tested on OS 5.0.1 and set `null` to cover works: cover cleared